# Which pygame should i install?

Tags: python, installation, version, pygame

Im running Mac OS 10.8.3 and python/idle 2.7.5.

I tried to install pygame 1.9.1 but it didnt work. Is this the right pygame? if not which is?

Comment: you installed http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I installed "Lion apple supplied python: pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip"
Then i went into terminal and tried to import pygame through Aplle python and it prompted me to install "Xquartz" after i did this pygame works in both Terminal and 64 bit Idle 2.7.5.